# What is the best way to compare two doc files and see the changes

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, automation

**My task:**
I have to compare two .docx files and see all the changes between them highlighted.

**My problems:**

- The simple MS Word "Side by side" view doesn't show the difference or highlight the similarities.
- The "Compare" tool is not convenient because the results of comparison are poorly highlighted.

**My specific question:**
How can I do it in a 'code comparison' way as in VS Code or JB WebStorm?

**In addition:**
The docs may have similar text, but the fonts may differ, there may be some additional spaces etc.

**How I want to see it:**
[image: Jetbrain Example]

Answer (score 0):

I don't the exact way, but sometimes I use https://text-compare.com/ to compare my code if the code is not long enough.

It's good to try to use git to compare the code, I Use them to compare before and after code refactor. But you need to commit the first change and then write some code.
go to left sidebar
open source control and click the file
it will look like this
[source contrl vs code diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0EZh.png)

i hope this can help you.
thank you

Answer (score -1):

### Are you sure you can't get what you need using the Compare Tool?

Try the document Compare tool again and refine the controls for both what is checked, i.e. leave out the formatting, and how it is displayed. Then tinker under Track Changes for how things are displayed.

The big two options are in balloons or in-line-with text.